# ListView doesn't show any data in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to implement `SimpleCursorAdapter` which takes data from database and displays it. Till now I was using `ArrayAdapter` which was working perfectly.
But Since I changed the code for `CursorAdapter`, it shows nothing on fragment.
The Cursor stores data in `ListView`.

Here's the fragment class (A lot of code though):

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
{


    //ArrayAdapter<String>  mForecastAdapter;
    /**Change to cursor Adapter*/
    SimpleCursorAdapter mForecastAdapter;
    String Cityname;
    /*Loader Id**/
    private String mLocation;
    private final static int FORECAST_LOADER = 0;

    // Projection columns
    private static final String[] FORECAST_COLUMNS = {
            WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + WeatherEntry._ID,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING,
            WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG
    };
  // Indices for forecast column
    static final int COL_WEATHER_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_DATE=1;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_DESC=2;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP=3;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP = 4;
    static final int COL_LOCATION_SETTING =5;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID=6;
    static final int COL_COORD_LAT =7;
    static final int COL_COORD_LONG =8;



    public ForecastFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER,null,this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment,menu);
    }

    private void updateWeather(){
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask(getContext());
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
        weatherTask.execute(location);
        //  weatherTask.execute("201014");
        //return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateWeather();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_refresh)
        {
            updateWeather();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
    {
       /* String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());


        //Sort Order ; ASC(Date)
        String sortOrder = WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + "ASC";
        Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());*/

        String startDate = WeatherContract.getDbDateString(new java.util.Date());

        // Sort order: Ascending, by date
        String sortOrder = WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";

        mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
        Uri weatherForLocationUri = WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(mLocation, System.currentTimeMillis()/*startDate*/);

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity()
                ,weatherForLocationUri
                ,FORECAST_COLUMNS
                ,null
                ,null
                ,sortOrder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String [] forecastArray = {
                "today-sunny-88/63",
                "tomorrow-foggy-70/40",
                "weds-cloudy-72/63",
                "thurs-asteroids-75/65",
                "fri-heavy rain-65/56",
                "sat-day off - 55/55",
                "sun - i dont know- 80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

       /* //ArrayAdapter<String>
                mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            //The current context (parent activity)
                getActivity(),

            // ID of list item layout
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            // ID of text view
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            // list of data
            weekForecast
        );*/

       mForecastAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
               //The current context (parent activity)
               getActivity(),

               // ID of list item layout
               R.layout.list_item_forecast,
               null,
               //column nmaes
               new String[]{
                       WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                       WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
                       WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
                       WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP},

               // ID of text view
               new int[]{
                       R.id.list_item_date_textview,
                       R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                       R.id.list_item_high_textview,
                       R.id.list_item_low_textview

               },0

       );
      // forecast bind
        mForecastAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                boolean isMetric = Utility.isMetric(getActivity());
                switch (columnIndex) {
                    case COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP:
                    case COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP:
                        // we have to do some formatting and possibly a conversion
                        ((TextView) view).setText(Utility.formatTemperature(cursor.getDouble(columnIndex), isMetric));
                        return true;
                    case COL_WEATHER_DATE:
                        String dateString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        TextView dateView = (TextView) view;
                        dateView.setText(Utility.formatDate(dateString));
                        return true;
                }

                // If return false, 2 types of binding will occur
                // 1: view is a TextView, SimpleCursorAdapter#setViewText(TextView, String) is called
                // 2: view is a ImageView, SimpleCursorAdapter#setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) is called
                return false;
            }
        });


        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        // for clicking
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
            {
               /* String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),forecast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,forecast);

                startActivity(intent);*/

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here's the list_item_forecast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_date_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_emptyview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_high_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_slash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:text="/" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_low_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

There's no error. `Logcat` shows data has been fetched properly from database.
Database and other function are working fine. I just can't see any data on the fragment.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have made the same mistake as me. The Fragment default textColor is white and the visibility of an image is invisible. Therefore you should set text color black and the visibility attribute visible;